# Was impersonating an Egyptian once a capital offense in England?

Tags: law

This [site](http://convictcreations.com/culture/facts.htm) claims that:

> Serious crimes, such as murder, rape,
>   or impersonating an Egyptian were
>   given the death sentence in England.

Is that true?

Comment: Heh. I've heard this before, but with the caveat that "impersonating an Egyptian" was technical way of referring to gypsies, and therefore the crime in question was incorrigible vagrancy, not actual impersonation. I'll see if I can find a primary source for that.

Comment: I have never heard this claim before, but it is _awesome_

Comment: Doesn't it sound that the very word Gipsies is a changed with time word Egyptians?

Comment: Yes, Gino, that's where the word Gypsy is from (but, not the people). http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=gypsy

Answer (score 24, accepted):

In England a law of 1713 outlawed

> all Persons pretending to be Gipsies, or Wandering in the Habit or Form of Counterfeit Egyptians, or pretending to have Skill in Physiognomy, Palmestry, or the like Crafty Science, or pretending to tell Fortunes or like Phantastical Imaginations, or using any Subtle Craft, or Unlawful Games or Plays

Source: The Gypsies, by Angus M. Frasier, 1995: Blackwell Publishing. Page 136. [Amazon Link](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0631196056)

It was [not a capital offense](http://www.timesonline.co.uk/tol/comment/article1009858.ece).

Comment: "The last person hanged as a wandering Gypsy was in the 1650s" So it would seem that Gypsies were at some stage hanged for just being Gypsies

Comment: The law was the Vagrancy Act 1713.  Page [134 of The Gypsies](http://books.google.co.uk/books?id=qHUdwpiYCtIC&lpg=PA136&ots=ZRRUPXE990&dq=%22Habit%20or%20Form%20of%20Counterfeit%20Egyptians%22&pg=PA134#v=onepage&q=%22Habit%20or%20Form%20of%20Counterfeit%20Egyptians%22&f=false) describes a 1572 statute where a person taken as a Rogue, Vagabond or sturdy Beggar three times would be treated as a felon "with terminal consequences". Earlier it describes the execution of foreign-born Gypsies.

Comment: @Casebash: I think there's an implication that pretending to be one and being one were two different acts.

Comment: Or just that Gypsies told people they were Egyptians